# object array for user defined class in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsarray

hai folks,
         i want to create array for user defined class like in java.
eg in java:

```
ClassA[] obj=new ClassA[10];
```

like this i want to make a array in objective-c, and also i want to return this object in the method.

eg in java:

```
ClassA[] method1()
{
     ClassA[] classA=new ClassA[10];

   return classA;
}
```

is it possible to do this one, without using NSArray. if it possible, how can i do this one in objective-c.

plz give me some sample code snippet for this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use NSArray? What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in C style:

```
ClassA *objCollection[10];
objCollection = (ClassA *)malloc(sizeof(ClassA)*10);
objCollection[0] = [[ClassA alloc] init];
objCollection[1] = [[ClassA alloc] init];
...
```

In this way you are declaring a array of pointers to `ClassA` objects of size 10.

Comment: Why was this voted down?  Aside from some typos `(Class A **) malloc(10 * sizeof(ClassA *))` this would work.

Answer (score 0):

There is rarely a reason to avoid NSArray.  However, if you are *absolutely certain* that you have one of those cases, then use the C idiom, because Obj-C is a superset of C.